# Struggling to apply the Implicit function theorem

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

I'm struggling with applying the implicit function theorem for the following expression. As an economist I'm not sure if I'm missing something extremely easy, if so, I apologise. For other derivatives in the paper I'm successful using the IFT. Any help at pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Let $c^*$ be defined implicitly as
\begin{equation}
c^*=\frac{b(e)y+a\int_0^{c^*}c\;G(c)\;dc}{r+b(e)+aG(c^*)}
\end{equation}
where $G$ is a distribution.
I would like to find the following derivative $\frac{dc^*}{de}$. The papaer I'm reading states that
\begin{equation}
\frac{dc^*}{de} = \frac{(y-c^*)b'(e)}{r+b(e)+aG(c^*)}
\end{equation}

The idea is to use the implicit function theorem on $H(c^*,e)=c^*-\frac{b(e)y+a\int_0^{c^*}c\;G(c)\;dc}{r+b(e)+aG(c^*)}$ which should give
\begin{equation}
\frac{dc^*}{de} = - \frac{\frac{\partial H}{\partial e}}{\frac{\partial H}{\partial c^*}}
\end{equation}

I find
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial H}{\partial e} = -\frac{b'(e)(r+b(e)+aG(c^*))-b'(e)(b(e)y+a\int_{0}^{c^*}cG(c)dc)}{(r+b(e)+aG(c^*))^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial H}{\partial c^*} = 1-\frac{ac^*G(c^*)(r+b(e)+aG(c^*))-aG'(c^*)(b(e)y+a\int_{0}^{c^*}cG(c)dc)}{(r+b(e)+aG(c^*))^2}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it easier to type the variable $c^* $ as $C$ in what follows.

P.S. This revised answer  corrects a mistake I made earlier when I tried to type (1). However, even with this corrected equation for (1)  as written below, I still am unable to reconcile the results that you reported  occurred in the paper. Perhaps that paper has a typo??

The easiest way to apply the implicit function theorem is to first completely clear of denominators:  re-write your initial identity as

(1) $$0= C (r + b(e) + a G(C)) -b(e)y - a \int _0^C cG(c)dc= H(C, e)$$

With this choice of the implicit defining function $H(e,C)$ you see readily that
$$\partial H/\partial C= (r + b(e) + a G(C)) + a C G'(C) - a CG(C)  = r+ b(e) + a CG'(C) + a G(C) - a CG(C)$$

and $\partial H/\partial e= (C-y) b'(e) $

hence

$dC/de=- \frac{\partial H/\partial e}{\partial H /\partial C}=- \frac{(C-y) b'(e)}{ r+ b(e) + a CG'(C) + a G(C) - a CG(C)}$

This answer disagrees with what you claim the paper asserts. Perhaps there was a  typo in the paper you read, or perhaps you mistyped the equations that were in that paper?

Comment: Yep that exactly what I needed to do! In fact you made a typo when defining $H(C,e)$. The integral is missing the $C$ multiplying $G(c)$ in the integrand. Correct answer follows after that. Thanks!